# Does this sentence need a conjunction?

Tags: conjunctions, comma-splices

Does the sentence, "Charles is not only persistent, he is also driven to gain new knowledge" need a conjunction? Or is this a comma splice?

Comment: Where would you find room for the conjunction? And why the word 'also' after you said 'not only'?

Comment: I guess the thinking would be that the word "but" should be before "he". However, I don't feel like it needs it.

Comment: ... It's got one.

Comment: I should have specified coordinating conjunction my question. My bad. I realize the sentence is not well written, particularly with the "also" in the second clause, but is this grammatically correct as written? I'm mainly asking because of a potential test question. I'm arguing that this sentence cannot be eliminated as a potential answer choice due to it technically being a sound sentence, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Neither a "but" nor an "also" are essential. One could say " Charles is not only persistent, he is driven to gain new knowledge". However, the "also" improves understanding, in my view. The "but" is entirely optional.

Comment: The correlative conjunction is "not only...but also". I would write "Charles is not only persistent but also driven to gain new knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence sounds grammatically correct as it stands. It doesn't have a comma splice, and it already has a conjunction.

A comma splice requires the parts on both sides of the comma to be complete (or *main*) sentences:

> A comma splice, also called a run-on, occurs when a writer has connected two main clauses with a comma alone. A main clause makes a complete thought, so you should not find a wimpy comma struggling to join two such powerful clauses.
>   [- Grammar Bytes!](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/commasplice.htm)

In your quote, "Charles is not only persistent" is *not* main clause because "not only ... but also" is a [correlative conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(grammar)#Correlative_conjunctions) - both parts must occur within the same main clause [as a pair](http://www.talkenglish.com/grammar/conjunctions-coordinating-correlative.aspx).

Although your quote doesn't include the word "but" before "also", the "Charles is not only ..., he is also ..." structure it uses is an acceptable variant.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your input. You helped my understanding a bunch.